# How to transform integer that follow another word into its string value?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that transforms an integer into its string value only if this integer follows certains words.
So, I want all the numbers that follow only words such as "hours", "hour", "day", "days", "minutes" to be transformed into their string value, otherwise, kept the same.

So for example, i have this : "I am 45, I came here 4 times and I have been waiting for 6 hours."
The result should be : "I am 45, I came here four times and I have been waiting for six hours."

I tried to write a code for that but i am stuck at some point:

1. I am able to get the result in the previous case, but when i have something like:
   "I am 45, I came here 4 times and I have been waiting for 45 hours.", my code returns
   "I am forty-five , I came here 4 times and I have been waiting for forty-five hours." while i don't want the first "45" to be changed.
2. When i test my code with a single sentence it works, but when i use an entire dataframe column with the map function, it's not working.
   Here is my code and the error i get.

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   from num2words import num2words
   import re

   text = [[1, "I am writing some very basic english sentences"],
              [2, " i am 45 old and worked 3 times this week for 45 hours " ],
               [3, " i am 75 old and worked 6 times this week for 45 hours "]]

   Data = pd.DataFrame(raw_docs, columns=["index", "text"])
   Data

   def remove_numbers(text):
       m = re.findall('\d+\s(?=hour|day|days|hours|hrs|hr|minutes|min|time|times)', text)
       for i in range(len(m)):
           if m[i]:
               t = m[i]
               t2 = num2words(t) 
               clean = re.sub(t, t2+' ', text)
               text = clean
       return clean

   Data['text'] = pd.DataFrame(Data['text'].map(remove_numbers))
   Data['text']
   ```

The error i get:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-165-b46ce833010e> in <module>
         16     return clean
         17 
    ---> 18 Data['text'] = pd.DataFrame(Data['text'].map(remove_numbers))
         19 Data['text']
    
    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
       3907         dtype: object
       3908         """
    -> 3909         new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
       3910         return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index).__finalize__(
       3911             self, method="map"
    
    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
        935 
        936         # mapper is a function
    --> 937         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
        938 
        939         return new_values
    
    pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
    
    <ipython-input-165-b46ce833010e> in remove_numbers(text)
         14             clean = re.sub(t, t2+' ', text)
         15             text = clean
    ---> 16     return clean
         17 
         18 Data['text'] = pd.DataFrame(Data['text'].map(remove_numbers))
    
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'clean' referenced before assignment
```

Please, can someone help me solve those 2 issues ?

Comment: The unbound error is being caused because your function returns `clean`, but it's defined in that `if` block. So if it's not executed, then clean is not defined,and you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

The last error is whats getting you. In your example text[0][1] has no matches for m so it returns clean before it has been set to anything.

try:

```py
def remove_numbers(text):
    m = re.findall('\d+\s(?=hour|day|days|hours|hrs|hr|minutes|min|time|times)', text)
    clean = text
    for i in range(len(m)):
        if m[i]:
            t = m[i]
            t2 = num2words(t) 
            clean = re.sub(t, t2+' ', text)
            text = clean
    return clean
```

### UPDATE

Forgot about the first part of the question, you'll need to apply the regex when substituting the new value. When you search for 45 in the case of text[1][1] it's replacing both instances.

try:

```py
def remove_numbers(text):
    clean = text
    m = re.findall('\d+\s(?=hour|day|days|hours|hrs|hr|minutes|min|time|times)', text)
    print(m)
    for i in range(len(m)):
        if m[i]:
            t = m[i]
            t2 = num2words(t) 
            pattern = '[' + t + ']+\s(?=hour|day|days|hours|hrs|hr|minutes|min|time|times)'
            clean = re.sub(pattern, ' '+ t2 + ' ', text)
            text = clean
    return clean
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works for the 2nd part. But, the 1st part of my question remains the same. Anything to propose ?

Comment: Go ahead and apply the regex pattern again, see my update. I think that'll fix your issues.